# CSS absolute/relative positioning in flyout menu: How to use only part of parents' properties (left,top,width,vertical/horizontal alignment)?

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-position

This is a problem which I stumbled upon recently quite often in CSS. Lets assume we have a flyout menu somewhere in the page which has list items. Those list items have sub-menus which are shown on hover. Because I want the sub-menu to appear right below the parent list item I give `position:relative;` to the parent item and `position:absolute;top:0;` to the submenu. So far this works great.

However because of `position:relative;` now I have lost the ability to make the submenu 100% width of page width and to use `left:0;` in the sense that the submenu is aligned to the very left *of the page* not of the parent element.

What I want is to somehow have `position:relative;` on the parent for the vertical alignment, but `position:inherit;` regarding the horizontal alignment.

See the following example - the submenus are aligned correctly in vertical terms but should start to the very left in horizontal terms:

```css
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul {
  width:100%;
  background-color:yellow;
  list-style-type:none;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul > li {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:20px;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul > li > div.sub {
   position:absolute;
   top:60px;
   background-color:red;
   padding:40px;
   display:none;
   left:0;
   width:100vw;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul > li:hover > div.sub, #my-menu-inner > ul > li:focus > div.sub {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="whatever">Just something before ...</div>
<div id="my-menu">
  <div id="my-menu-inner">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li>
        <span>foo</span>
        <div class="sub">
          <ul>
            <li>hello</li>
            <li>world</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>foo</span>
        <div class="sub">
          <ul>
            <li>please</li>
            <li>alignme</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve what I want (please only pure CSS, answers involving JS will not be accepted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the menu item positioned relatively to the `ul` rather than the `li`:

```css
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul {
  margin:10px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:yellow;
  list-style-type:none;
  position:relative;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul > li {
  float:left;
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:20px;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul > li > div.sub {
   position:absolute;
   top:calc(100%  - 20px);
   background-color:red;
   padding:40px;
   display:none;
   left:0;
   width:100vw;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul > li:hover > div.sub, #my-menu-inner > ul > li:focus > div.sub {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="whatever">Just something before ...</div>
<div id="my-menu">
  <div id="my-menu-inner">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li>
        <span>foo</span>
        <div class="sub">
          <ul>
            <li>hello</li>
            <li>world</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>foo</span>
        <div class="sub">
          <ul>
            <li>please</li>
            <li>alignme</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sometimes I happen to be blind to the most obvious solution  This is how to do it.